# Как сделать выход из аккаунта?

Tags: php

Всем привет. В админке сайта для её запароливания используется следующий код:

```
<?php
  if (!isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']))
  {
    Header ("WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm=\"Admin Page\"");
    Header ("HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized");
    exit();
  }

  else {
    if (!get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
            $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'] = mysql_escape_string($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']);
            $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'] = mysql_escape_string($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']);
    }

    $query = "SELECT pass FROM userlist WHERE user='".$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']."'";
    $lst = @mysql_query($query);

    if (!$lst)
    {
        Header ("WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm=\"Admin Page\"");
    Header ("HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized");
    exit();
    }

    if (mysql_num_rows($lst) == 0)
    {
       Header ("WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm=\"Admin Page\"");
       Header ("HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized");
       exit();
    }

    $pass =  @mysql_fetch_array($lst);
    if ($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']!= $pass['pass'])
    {
        Header ("WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm=\"Admin Page\"");
       Header ("HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized");
       exit();
    }
}
?>
```

Как реализовать выход из админки? Чтобы по клику на ссылку из админки выкидывало и вскакивала форма ввода логина и пароля?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php
    header( 'Location: /index.php', true, 303 );
    header("Cache-Control : no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0");
    session_start();
    setcookie ("login", "", time()-14800);
    setcookie ("password", "", time()-14800);
    session_destroy();
?>
```

Вот как это реализовано у меня...

Answer (score 1):

Ну тут думаю надо убить сессию и куда-то человека перенаправить чтобы сессионные данные перегрузились:

```
session_unset ();
session_destroy ();

header ("Location: login.php?logout=1");
exit;
```

Comment: и еще как вариант убить переменные сервера рассказывающие ему про аутентификацию :  

    unset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'],  $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']);

Comment: Ну я второй вариант пробовал, мессивы удалял, но ничего не происходило.

Comment: И первый вариант ошибку выдаёт.

Comment: как бы http аутентификация не предназначена была для выхода, потому как вариан попробуйте перенаправить пользователя на 401 страницу в том же каталоге. А там проверить параметры $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'] и $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'] и один из них удалить или подменить на пустой.