# Возможно ли удалить переменную супер глобального массива?

Tags: php

Например, `$_SERVER["PHP_AUTH_USER"]`

Пробовал функцию `unset`, но не помогло.

---

в начале админки есть код

```
if (!isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'])){
        header ("WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm=\"Admin Page\"");
        header ("HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized");
        exit();
}
```

то есть чтобы переавторизоватся мне где то из другого места кода нужно удалить элемент `$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']`

Comment: вообще говорят _unset_ работает, можешь развернуть вопрос?

Comment: @Grundy, дополнил

Comment: что значит _начало админки_? где ты пробовал применять вызов _unset_?

Comment: и что значит _переавторизоваться из другого места_?

Comment: @Grundy, админка - это блок администратора управления сайтом, в начале каждой страницы этого блока вставлен этот код (который я привел, но он не весь канечно), unset я вызываю с отдельной специальной страницы, где никакого кода нет кроме самого вызова unset, переавторизоваться - сменить текущую учетную запись на другую.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это интересный вопрос, и он оказывается немного сложнее, если прочитать не один только заголовок, но и сам текст вопроса.

Для ответа на него требуется [понимание того, как в принципе работает РНР](http://phpfaq.ru/newbie/na_tanke).

поэтому ответа будет два:

1. Удалить элемент из суперглобального массив, разумеется, можно.
2. Но это вам не поможет.

Поскольку эти переменные заполняются заново с каждым запросом, из приходящих НТТР заголовков. То есть, на самом деле вопрос звучит, как

### Можно ли заставить браузер не передавать определенный НТТР заголовок?

Ответ: нельзя.

HTTP basic authentication так устроена, что браузер передает логин и пароль с каждым запросом. Если он не будет их передавать, то РНР скрипт о них не узнает, и пользователь не сможет просмотреть запароленную страницу.

При этом механизма логаута в HTTP basic authentication не предусмотрено.

Можно только запросить пароль повторно, но если пользователь проигнорирует этот запрос, то браузер продолжит присылать старые логин и пароль. Лет 15 назад я довольно долго копал эту тему ,и даже сделал демо-страничку, которая разлогинивала-таки пользователя... но самые способные могли обнаружить, что этот трюк исполнялся с помощью банальной куки 8)

Comment: доходчиво, спасибо

Comment: и я видимо по этому пути иду. мне теперь этот способ авторизации странным кажется что никак без костылей не обойтись. эх автор так хвалил эту технологию, что я ее применил не вникая. ну хоть урок на будущее теперь будет

Comment: @perfect для простой админки это хороший вариант, но для чего-то более сложного он не годится.

Comment: админка то простая, но у нее два администратора

Comment: это случайно не эта фишка с кукой? http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/231105/2872

Comment: @perfect нет это не мое, но похоже

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте сделать unset нескольких функций .

```
    unset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'],  $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']);
    header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Auth"');
    header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
```

Comment: ошибаетесь это серверные переменные к которым доступ имеет только php

Comment: @perfect протестируйте предложенный мною вариант, вообще должен выполняться с перенаправлением на 401 страницу

Comment: мой код вообще не использует сессий, и как бы это не ответ на мой вопрос

Comment: Я отредактировал ответ, для удаления запустите unset для 2х переменных с перенаправлением на 401